# mariadb update with multiple where conditions from separate tables

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb

I am trying to update a field in a table based on conditions from two tables

```
update a,
    b
set a.`value` = '1265'
where a.`id` = b.`ID`
    and b.`type` = 'product'
    and a.`key` = '1234'
```

This returns "`0 rows affected.`"

Comment: It should work. Probably there are no matching rows to update.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn - Yes.Even though I am not a fan of comma based style, this should work.

Comment: maybe field is case sensitive?   a.id = b.ID

Comment: @nicas1 can you post your data thanks

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables.

Comment: Apart from `rows affected`, you should also be able to see how many rows matched the condition. If you have `Rows matched: 0`, it indeed means that no rows meeting the condition were found. But if you have `0 rows affected`, while `Rows matched` shows a non-zero value, it means that rows were found, but they already have `value = '1265'`.

Comment: Thank you everyone, @elenst was correct, I didn't realize that all the records in the table already had the value = '1265'.  Thank you everyone for the feedback.

Comment: Also @GurV.  Thanks